# fixing margin and padding on navigtion bar dropdown

Tags: css

currently when you hover over the drop down you will see the drop down links. in the drop down menu  to the left of the links there is a gap. I would like that gap removed.

this is for my navigation bar drop down in desktop mode only.

this for my website JGittech.com.

it needs me to type more

all help would be appreciated

```css
/*! CSS Used from: https://jgittech.com/stylesheets/nav.v5.css */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif
}

.menu-item-has-children .menu-li .nav-ul-li-a:hover,.sub-menu .menu-li .nav-ul-li-a:hover,.sub-menu .menu-li:hover {
    background: #006084;
    color: #fff
}

.navcontainer {
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%
}

.active {
    background: #009fd8;
    color: #fff
}

.main-navigation {
    background: #333
}

.nav-ul,body {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}

.fixednav,.menu {
    display: flex
}

.menu {
    flex-direction: column
}

.menu-li {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none
}

.menu .nav-ul-li-a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 1rem
}

.menu-li .nav-ul-li-a:hover,a:hover {
    color: #fff
}

.nav-ul-ul {
    display: none
}

.nav-ul .menu-li:hover>ul {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    color: #fff
}

.fixednav {
    flex-direction: row;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px
}

.leftnav {
    line-height: 20px
}

@media (min-width:800px) {
    .menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-start
    }

    .nav-ul .menu-li:hover>ul {
        background: #333
    }

    .nav-ul .menu-li:hover>.nav-ul-li-a,.sub-menu .menu-li .nav-ul-li-a:hover,.sub-menu .menu-li:hover {
        background: #006084;
        color: #fff
    }

    .sub-menu .menu-li {
        display: flex;
        padding-right: 1em
    }

    .nav-ul-ul {
        position: absolute
    }

    .nav-ul-ul,input[data-function*=swipe],label[data-function*=swipe] {
        display: none
    }
}

@media (max-width:799px) {
    .nav-ul .menu-li:hover>ul {
        background: #263249
    }

    .nav-ul .menu-li:hover>.nav-ul-li-a {
        color: #fff
    }

    .menu-item-has-children .menu-li .nav-ul-li-a:hover,.sub-menu .menu-li .nav-ul-li-a:hover,.sub-menu .menu-li:hover {
        background: #006084;
        color: #fff
    }

    .fixednav,.nav-ul-ul {
        display: block
    }

    label[data-function*=swipe] {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        left: 30px;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 42px;
        height: 42px;
        font: 42px fontawesome;
        text-align: center;
        color: #333;
        cursor: pointer;
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        transition: transform .3s
    }

    .fixednav {
        text-align: left
    }

    .menu .nav-ul-li-a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0 20px;
        color: #fff;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 900;
        padding: 20px 1rem;
        margin: 0 20px
    }

    .nav1contain {
        display: flex;
        height: 60px
    }

    input[data-function*=swipe] {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0
    }

    label[data-function*=swipe]:hover {
        color: #263249
    }

    input[data-function*=swipe]:checked~label[data-function*=swipe] {
        transform: translate3d(280px,0,0)
    }

    label[data-function*=swipe]:checked {
        display: block
    }

    label:nth-child(2) {
        display: none
    }

    input[data-function*=swipe]:checked~label:nth-child(2) {
        display: block;
        transform: translate3d(280px,0,0)
    }

    input[data-function*=swipe]:checked~label:nth-child(3) {
        display: none
    }

    input[data-function*=swipe]:checked~.sidebar {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
    }

    input[data-function*=swipe]:checked~.sidebar .menu-li {
        width: 100%
    }

    .sidebar {
        transform: translate3d(-280px,0,0);
        position: absolute;
        width: 280px;
        background: #263249;
        color: #eee;
        left: 0;
        transition: all .3s
    }

    .menu-li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
        list-style: none;
        background: #263249;
        list-style-type: none
    }

    .menu-item-has-children:hover {
        display: block
    }
}

.button {
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    height: 40px;
    margin: 2% 15px;
    background-color: #009fd8;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 9px rgba(50,50,93,.06),0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.08),inset 0 1px 0 #ffb9f6;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer
}

.active2 {
    background: #00569b;
    color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="nav1contain">
  <input data-function="swipe" id="swipe" type="checkbox">
  <label data-function="swipe" for="swipe">&#xf057;</label>
  <label data-function="swipe" for="swipe">&#xf0c9;</label>
  <div class="navcontainer sidebar">
    <nav class="main-navigation fixednav menu">
      <ul class="menu nav-ul">
        <li class = "menu-li"><a class = " active leftnav nav-ul-li-a" href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class = "menu-li"> <a class = "nav-ul-li-a " href="pages/about.html">About</a> </li>
        <li class = "menu-li"> <a class = "nav-ul-li-a" href="pages/products.html">Products</a> </li>
        <li class = "menu-li"> <a class = "nav-ul-li-a" href="pages/contact.html">Contact</a> </li>
        <li class = "menu-li"> <a class = "nav-ul-li-a" href="https://statuspage.freshping.io/13300-JGittechLLCStatusPage/check/91333">Status</a> </li>
        <li class = "menu-li"> <a class = "nav-ul-li-a" href="../sitemap.html">Sitemap</a> </li>
        <li class = "menu-li"> <a class = "nav-ul-li-a" href="pages/video.html">Videos</a> </li>
        <li class="menu-item-has-children menu-li"> <a class ="nav-ul-li-a" href="#">Legal +</a>
          <ul class="nav-ul-ul">
            <li class = "menu-li"> <a class = "nav-ul-li-a" href="pages/legal/terms.pdf">Terms of Use</a> </li>
            <li class = "menu-li"> <a class = "nav-ul-li-a" href="pages/legal/privacy.pdf">Privacy Policy</a> </li>
            <li class = "menu-li"> <a class = "nav-ul-li-a" href="pages/legal/disclaimer.pdf">Disclaimer Policy</a> </li>
            <li class = "menu-li"><a class = "nav-ul-li-a" href="pages/legal/cookie.html">Cookie Policy</a> </li>
            <li class = "menu-li"> <a class = "nav-ul-li-a" href="pages/legal/return.pdf">Return Policy</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

.

Comment: I am really not sure what you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.nav-ul-ul { padding:0; }` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the help mr/ms jdfink

Comment: No problem! Happy to help